# Regarding program that calculates time through keypad

Tags: c#

A mobile phone has 12 keys for input, (‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’, ‘4’, ‘5’, ‘6’, ‘7’, ‘8’, ‘9’, ‘0’, ‘*’ and ‘#’).

In standard text input mode each key can be used to input the letters of the alphabet and the space character. For example, to access the letter ‘b’ the user would press the ‘2’ key twice.

It takes a user a minimum of 100 ms to press a key. If a user has to use the same key to input consecutive characters there must be at least a 0.5 second pause for the phone to accept that the next key press represents a new character.

I want to write an console application which accepts any string that can be entered using the key assignments in the grid using C#. The application should accept input from a user and calculate the minimum time required for the user to input that string using the key pad and the sequence of keys that would be required.

If somebody know who can help me to write program.

Comment: This looks like homework or a contest programming problem.  If so, please add the homework tag.  Either way, tell us what you have tried instead of just posting the prompt.

Comment: Do you want to let the user enter the string the same way as on a mobile phone? So he needs to enter `2`.`2`...`2`.`7`.`7`.`7`to enter `"bar"` and you want to calculate the required average time(in this example 1.1 sec)?

Comment: Yes Tim. You got it correct way. Now, how can I design mobile pad kind of look in console?

Comment: Hi Adam, I have tried below code to write. This is not a homework, I am just trying to solve it as I came through this problem on internet.
var KeyMap = new Dictionary<char, List<char>>
             {
                 { '1', new List<char>(), },  
                 { '2', new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c' } },
               ... so on
             };

Comment: `If somebody know who can help me to write program` Show what you have done so far. Otherwise I'll repeat my answer http://www.freelancer.com/

Comment: Hey..I have written most of the program...If you want to see, please give me your email, I can forward you my code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea:

```
class Mobilegrid
{
    const int MIN_DURATION = 100;
    const int WAIT_DURATION = 500;

    private static Dictionary<Char, Tuple<Char, int>> Grid;
    static Mobilegrid()
    {
        Grid = new Dictionary<Char, Tuple<Char, int>>();
        Grid.Add('a', Tuple.Create('2', 1));
        Grid.Add('b', Tuple.Create('2', 2));
        Grid.Add('c', Tuple.Create('2', 3));
        Grid.Add('d', Tuple.Create('3', 1));
        Grid.Add('e', Tuple.Create('3', 2));
        Grid.Add('f', Tuple.Create('3', 3));
        Grid.Add('g', Tuple.Create('4', 1));
        Grid.Add('h', Tuple.Create('4', 2));
        Grid.Add('i', Tuple.Create('4', 3));
        Grid.Add('j', Tuple.Create('5', 1));
        Grid.Add('k', Tuple.Create('5', 2));
        Grid.Add('l', Tuple.Create('5', 3));
        Grid.Add('m', Tuple.Create('6', 1));
        Grid.Add('n', Tuple.Create('6', 2));
        Grid.Add('o', Tuple.Create('6', 3));
        Grid.Add('p', Tuple.Create('7', 1));
        Grid.Add('q', Tuple.Create('7', 2));
        Grid.Add('r', Tuple.Create('7', 3));
        Grid.Add('s', Tuple.Create('7', 4));
        Grid.Add('t', Tuple.Create('8', 1));
        Grid.Add('u', Tuple.Create('8', 2));
        Grid.Add('v', Tuple.Create('8', 3));
        Grid.Add('w', Tuple.Create('9', 1));
        Grid.Add('x', Tuple.Create('9', 2));
        Grid.Add('y', Tuple.Create('9', 3));
        Grid.Add('z', Tuple.Create('9', 4));
    }

    public static int CalculateMinimumTime(String word)
    {
        int totalMillis = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < word.Length; index++)
        {
            Tuple<Char, int> charInfo = Grid[word[index]];
            int Pos = charInfo.Item2;
            int clickTime = Pos * MIN_DURATION;
            if (index != 0)
            {
                Tuple<Char, int> lastCharInfo = Grid[word[index - 1]];
                if (lastCharInfo.Item1 == charInfo.Item1)
                    clickTime += WAIT_DURATION;
            }
            totalMillis += clickTime;
        }
        return totalMillis;
    }
}
```

Then you'd get the total minimum required time:

```
int totalMillis = Mobilegrid.CalculateMinimumTime("hello"); //1800
```

Note: you have to add special chars like white-space.

Comment: No I don't..see the comments.

Comment: Some people just comment, don't respond.
Thanks so much Tim. I really appreciate your time and efforts to give me solution. One more thing, can I have your email so, I can contact you further if I need you in future.

Comment: @L.B: So you're downvoting because this question is a duplicate? Does the quality of a question correlates to an answer?

Comment: @user1262572: In general i agree with L.B (and others) that Stackoverflow is a site where people help **each other** and not only ask for code. So if you have a specific question and you can show what you've tried, your welcome to ask this question on SO, otherwise not.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I understand what you are saying. I am new to this, just posted a question only...I didn't know about I should put also my solution..next time, I will remember this.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, for whiespace I will be using below.
Grid.Add('SPACE', Tuple.Create('0', 1));
is this correct ? I could have use '#' or '+'

Comment: @user1262572: If you press `"0"` one time to enter a white-space, you need to add `Grid.Add(' ', Tuple.Create('0', 1));`

Comment: Hi @TimSchmelter, one question , what does this stmt do? int Pos = charInfo.Item2;

Comment: @user1262572: I'm storing in `Item2` of the [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) how often you need to press that number(stored in `Item1`). If it's at the third position, you must press this key 3 times.

Comment: Hey @TimSchmelter, one question, How would we design above application to allow the characters assigned to each key to be easily reconfigured?  or what will be the best approach?

Comment: Can anybody give any idea beside using dictionary class?

Comment: @Karan: What's the problem with using a `Dictioanary`? You could easily add configuration logic. For example: `public static void configureKey(Char charToConfigure, Char keyToPress, int position){ Grid[charToConfigure] = Tuple.Create(keyToPress,position);}`